# Ember Route only working on manual refresh

Tags: javascript, ember.js, routes, ember-router

Im pretty new at ember and I want to make Route work with a string instead of id for a prettier url. This Router code here is working when I enter the path manually example.com/#/Commune. But when using {{#linkTo "commune" name}}{{name}}{{/linkTo}} the url is changing correctly but nothing is showing (it does if i refresh the browser). any idea?

**JS:**

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route('commune', {path: "/:commune_name"});
});

App.CommuneRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return App.CommunesController.findProperty('name', params.commune_name);
    }
});
```

If I do this: it's the other way around. (links working but enter/refresh aint)

```
App.CommuneRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return App.Commune.find(params.commune_name);
    }
});
```

Comment: have you already checked whether you end up in the right controller after clicking on the link and if `params.commune_name` is set correctly? also, is `CommuneRoute` really your only route? (just wondering because of the `CommunesController`.)

Comment: Transitioned into 'commune' both on refresh/enter and then clicking the links

Comment: if I do this: `App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route('commune', {path: "/:commune_id"});
});

App.CommuneRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return App.Commune.find(params.commune_id);
    }
});` its the other way around, now the liks is working but on enter/refresh it crashes

Comment: hmm, and if you use `return App.Commune.find({name: params.commune_name});` (or maybe `return App.Commune.find({'name': params.commune_name});`) in your `CommuneRoute` with the old router?

Comment: They both only work on links, and not on enter/refresh :/

Comment: I'm trying with id now, just to see if it was the name thing, but still nothing. :/  heres the whole daam thing: https://gist.github.com/tcarlsen/30ff30a15cd9f1eaefc2   (sry for danish content)

Comment: weird, i have done [something similar](https://github.com/FinnMacCool/ember-rails-blog) (the interesting files are router.js, controllers/tagged_controller.js and routes/tagged_route.js all in app/assets/javascripts) and that works. the only remaining difference that's possibly important is that i use `resource` instead of `route` in my router.

Comment: that is... your dynamic segment and your model's attribute also have different names ("commune_name" and "name"). that's probably not it either, but you never know.

Comment: another possible culprit: you use `{{#each App.CommunesController}}` in your template. so i'm not sure if `this` in your `linkTo` actually refers to the object or the controller. replacing `this` with `name` or something like that may be worth a try.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28650/discussion-between-thomas-carlsen-and-finn-maccool)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

needed to add serialize to my route:

```
App.CommuneRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    serialize: function(model, params) {
        return {
            name: model._data.attributes.name
        };
    },
    model: function(params) {
        return App.CommunesController.findProperty('name', params.commune_name);
    }
});
```